# Manifest template to package any generic distribution of files

Tags: python, manifest, packaging

I have set of directories and files that I would like to "package up" and move to another system. These files are inputs for a scientific simulation, which produces output files in the directory structure.

I'm looking for a [manifest file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file) solution to help package up the input files, ignoring other files, so I can easily move the simulation around to a different system/location. My current method is to manually create the directory structure and pick the required files to copy, then create a tar.gz or zip file. This is slow and error-prone. Is there a generic way to do this?

I'm familiar with the [MANIFEST.in](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template) template file for Python's `setup.py sdist`, which is ideal, but I'm not sure how or if it could be used to help package any generic distribution of files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you build all the input files into a COM object and make them platform and programming language independent?

Comment: Given that OP mentions creating `.tgz` archives, I don't think you can assume they are transferring between Windows machines.

Comment: The Com objects are platform and programming language independent.
Check it http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx